# Why is the output for the char pointer p different for the main and the func function?

Tags: c, pointers

Since the pointer `p` is passed-by-pointer shouldn't the output in `main` be `"Hi there"`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *);

int main() {
    char *p = "Hello";
    func(p);
    puts(p);   //Hello <-- Shouldn't this be Hi there
    return 0;
}

void func(char *p) {
    p = (char *)malloc(100);
    strcpy(p, "Hi there");
    puts(p);  //Hi there  
}
```

Isn't the pointer passed to function `func` not the same as pointer `p` inside the function `func`?

Comment: The pointer `p` is not passed by pointer.  It is passed by value.  You give the pointer a new value inside `func`, but that doesn't change the pointer in the caller.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to `p` to `func`.

Comment: @SteveSummit but since p is a char array, then how p is passed by value. Isn't the base address of a pointer is passed in a function call?

Comment: @AshishKumar `p` is passed as a pointer to `func`, but you're trying to modify the pointer itself. You'd need to pass a pointer to a pointer to modify `p`.

Comment: Sir, you declared `char *p`!  So there's no question but that it's a pointer!

Comment: You have two *different* `char *p` variables, with different scope. The function `func()` ignores the value that was passed (which is  a *copy* of the `p` in `main`) and overwrites it with the result from `malloc`. Having the same name is of no consequence, and on return from the function that value is forgotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is not pass-by-reference, so when you write to `p` in `func`, you're writing to `func`'s copy of `p`, not `main`'s copy.

`p` is passed as a pointer to `func`, but you're trying to modify the pointer itself. You'd need to pass a pointer to a pointer to modify `p`.

To fix this issue, pass a pointer to `p` to `func`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char **);

int main(void) // int main(void) is more up-to-date
{
    char *p = "Hello";
    func(&p); // pass a pointer to p
    puts(p); // Hi there
    free(p); // free memory that you've allocated
    return 0;
}

void func(char **pp) // char ** for pointer-to-pointer
{
    *pp = malloc(100); // don't cast the result of malloc()
    strcpy(*pp, "Hi there"); // formatting, use *pp instead of p
    puts(*pp); // Hi there
}
```